# (DJANGO-ALLAUTH) Select a valid choice. google is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

I want to add a social app provider though Django admin/socialaccount/socialapp/add/. I keep getting the error below:

[image]

Even though I have already specified the app provide in the **settings.py** as followed:

```py
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        'SCOPE': [
            'profile',
            'email',
        ],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {
            'access_type': 'offline',
        }
    }
}
```

Having followed all the required steps in the docs, obtained client id and secret key
https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#google
and I also have refreshed, cleared cache, run makemigrations and migrate many times but the field won't show 'google' as the option.
Could you show me the way to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by adding this line to INSTALLED_APP in **settings.py**

```py
'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
```

The docs specified this in earlier section.